# How to retrieve all datas from the table in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

This is my controller code. But this is not working. What is the problem here?

```
  class Subnet_Behind_ClientController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        //
         $datas = Subnet_behind_client::all();
        $data = $datas->first();

        /*  $data = Subnet_behind_client::all();*/

        return view('subnet_behind_clients',compact('data'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //

        $data = Subnet_behind_client::create([
    'client_id' => $request->client_id,
    'ip_address' => $request->ip_address,
    'netmask' => $request->netmask,

    return view('subnet_behind_clients1',compact('data'));
    // other properties here
]);

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

     /*    $data = Subnet_behind_client::all();
         dd($data);

        $data->client_id = $request->client_id;
        $data->ip_address = $request->ip_address;
        $data->netmask = $request->netmask;*/
      //  $data->clients = $request->clients;

/*
         $data->created_at = new DateTime;
        $data->updated_at = new DateTime;*/
        $datas = Subnet_behind_client::all();
        $data = $datas->first();

        $data->client_id = $request->client_id;
        $data->ip_address = $request->ip_address;
        $data->netmask = $request->netmask;

        $data->save();
        return back();

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        //

          /* $data = Subnet_behind_client::all();*/
           $datas = Subnet_behind_client::all();
        $data = $datas->first();

        return view('view2',compact('data'));
    }

}
```

I tried to create another page for it to use the create method. Will this help? Since I thought I am updating the record and not adding it.

Comment: surely `first()` is always going to return one record? Where are you even using `first()`?

Comment: $data = Subnet_behind_client::all();      ....here in place of all()

Comment: so if you `dd($data);` what do you get?

Comment: not getting anything

Comment: can you please show us Subnet_behind_client class ?

Comment: Initialize you class and try    $data = new Subnet_behind_client;

Comment: i have added the complete class .plz let me know of the changes required

Comment: @gaan10: Check my UPDATE answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I want to set data for `User` then need to initialize instance for that before perform action with table;

```
$user = new User;//Object initialization
$user->username = $request->username;//Assign column value
$user->role_id = $request->role_id;//Assign column value
$user->email = $request->email;//Assign column value
$user->save();//Store records by `save` method

//Check for success
if($user){
    //Redirect success, with success message
}
else {
    //Redirect error, with error message
}
```

Review same at [basic of laravel Insert](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete).

**UPDATE**: Replace `show` method with below one

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
  $data = $datas->get();

  return view('view2',compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Is there any or what? Provide some hint that will help to sort out your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = Subnet_behind_client::create([
    'client_id' => $request->client_id,
    'ip_address' => $request->ip_address,
    'netmask' => $request->netmask,

    return view('subnet_behind_clients1',compact('data'));
    // other properties here
]);
```

here is one error, your return is inside `create()` method. It should be like this.

```
$data = Subnet_behind_client::create([
    'client_id' => $request->client_id,
    'ip_address' => $request->ip_address,
    'netmask' => $request->netmask,
]);


return view('subnet_behind_clients1',compact('data'));
```

Please explain which method are you calling from your routes so we can debug more easily.